# replace format of html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

this is the given format:

```
how are <a href="#" class="frnd_class">Piyush</a>you fine and you <a href="#" class="frnd_class">Praveen</a>
```

And, I need the below format by manipulating or replacing html using jquery:

```
<span>how are</span>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="frnd_class">Piyush</a>&nbsp;<span>you fine and you</span>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="frnd_class">Praveen</a>
```

Comment: So you want all spaces before and after anchor tags to be expressed with &nbsp; and any text outside of anchors to be wrapped within span tags? Is that the goal?

Comment: yes i need your help in this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.contents()` , `.each()` , `.html()` , `$.trim()` , `String.prototype.replace()`

```js
$("#pred_ques").on("blur", function() {
  var div = $("<div />").html($(this).val());
  div.contents().each(function(i, el) {
    var text = el.nodeValue,
      re = /\w+/i;
    if (el.nodeType === 3 && re.test(text)) {
      div.html(function(_, html) {
        return html.replace(text, ($("span", el.parentElement).length ? "&nbsp;" : "") + $("<span />", {
          html: $.trim(text)
        })[0].outerHTML + "&nbsp;")
      });
    }
  });

  $("#pred_ques_1").val($(div)[0].innerHTML)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" id="pred_ques" name="pred_ques" value='how are <a href="#" class="frnd_class">Piyush</a>you fine and you <a href="#" class="frnd_class">Praveen</a>'>
<input type="text" id="pred_ques_1" name="pred_ques_1" value=''>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5a9yft7h/2/

Comment: @SaurabhBharatiya _"this code is not working for me"_ Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: but sir, this content is placed into hidden text field and I want that how to use it and apply for hidden text field

Comment: @SaurabhBharatiya _"this content is placed into hidden text field and I want that how to use it and apply for hidden text field"_ not appear at text of Question ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: this is jsfiddle link where this code is placed http://jsfiddle.net/5a9yft7h/ and please tell me how to resolve it and I want to place output to another text fiield

Comment: when we add question mark or any text value in text field at last after anchor tag then it is not wrap in span tag http://jsfiddle.net/5a9yft7h/4/

Comment: @SaurabhBharatiya _"when we add question mark or any text value in text field at last after anchor tag"_ See original Question at _"this is the given format:`how are <a href="#" class="frnd_class">Piyush</a>you fine and you <a href="#" class="frnd_class">Praveen</a>
`"_ ; description of requirement does not include adding additional text to string ? Difficult to resolve Question if requirement is added to in comments . See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask